# How to use HttpClient to Post with Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I am trying to do the following curl (which works for me) in C# using HttpClient.

```
curl -X POST http://www.somehosturl.com \
     -u <client-id>:<client-secret> \
     -d 'grant_type=password' \
     -d 'username=<email>' \
     -d 'password=<password>' \
     -d 'scope=all
```

The C# Code:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new  
            System.Net.NetworkCredential ("my_client_id", "my_client_secret")
    };


    try
    {
        using(var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var activationUrl = "www.somehosturl.com";

            var postData = "grant_type=password&username=myemail@myemail.com&password=mypass&scope=all";
            var content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(activationUrl, content);
            if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return null;

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return result;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

When executed, just crashes out, doesnt even catch the exception

Normally I am able to GET and POST perfectly fine, but whats throwing me off is how to set the auth stuff (client-id and client-secret)

Comment: What do you mean by crashes? Are you running this inside VS? Did you turn on First Chance Exceptions?

Comment: Take a look at this Stackoverflow post to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23914662/1337635

Comment: could you please post your code including method signature.

Comment: Try enabling CLRE (From VS: go to 'DEBUG', 'Exceptions', check the 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' option ('Thrown' column) and press 'OK'. Then try to run your code again (this will only give you more information about the reason your app crashes, won't fix your problem, of course)

Comment: Don't ever catch exceptions that way! You're just ignoring the exception without even finding out what kind of exception it is. You'd be better off just removing the try/catch block. At worse, add code to display the exception to yourself for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't "just crash", nor do exceptions escape. Your code explicitly discards exceptions by using `catch(Exception){}`. It also ignores error codes by using `return null;` Fix the exception handling code, then post the stacktrace of the exception

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First you have to set the `Authorization`-Header with your `<clientid>` and `<clientsecret>`.

Instead of using `StringContent` you should use `FormUrlEncodedContent` as shown below:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myserver");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/path");

var byteArray = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("<clientid>:<clientsecret>");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "<email>"));
formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "<password>"));
formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "all"));

request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: You should explain *why* this is an answer to the question. Do you want to say that on top of having to set the authentication header, the OP passes post data in the wrong way ?

Comment: Thanks Alexander, this works great!  I am using Xamarin though so I couldn't use Encoding.ASCII, I had to use new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes().

Comment: Why do you use `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` instead of `request.Headers.Authorization`?

Comment: Can someone explain why need to change data to byteArray before passing to client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization ?

Comment: @dellos Because `Convert.ToBase64String()` has no overload which accepts a string value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-6.0

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler, No I thought about why need to cast the "<clientid>:<clientsecret>" string to byteArray first then cast it back to string? Is it for a security concert?

Comment: @dellos The second cast is not a plain text string but a base64 encoded one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Answer (score 29):

Try to place your credentials directly into the headers property of HttpClient.

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
       var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("my_client_id:my_client_secret");
       var header = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = header;

       return await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain why need to change data to byteArray before passing to client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization ?

Answer (score 5):

See [BasicAuthenticationHeaderValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue)

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
    = new BasicAuthenticationHeaderValue("login", "password");
```

Or use extensions from IdentityModel:

```
<PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="4.0.0" />

var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBasicAuthentication(login, password);
client.SetBearerToken(token);
```

Comment: You've written about `BasicAuthenticationHeaderValue` but provided link to `AuthenticationHeaderValue`, so your example is invalid in .Net 5.

Comment: For  IdentityModel, Bearer Authentication is different than Basic one. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/59670260/3142139]