# Protect credentials for private R repo in .Rprofile

Tags: r, authentication, authorization, credentials, cran

Unlike python pip, R seems to expose credentials configured for private R repositories defined in the `.Rprofile`. I suppose this is due to R treating the string as a URL.

```
local({r <- getOption("repos")
       r["Nexus"] <- "https://username:password@my-private-r-repo.com/repository/r-group"
       options(repos=r)
})
```

Then when I install a package:

```
> install.packages("shinydashboard")
trying URL 'https://username:password@my-private-r-repo.com/repository/r-group/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/shinydashboard_0.7.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-tgz' length 326031 bytes (318 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 318 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/7_/pt_pgg2j531f2jc_n5znht600000gn/T//RtmpZkpXkN/downloaded_packages
```

Does R have configuration options to prevent the exposure of credentials?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this (and other issues) using **renv and Authorization header**.
[renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/index.html) helps you to create virtual environments for R projects, locking all packages (and their versions) used in the project.
You can read about authentication headers here: [Web API Authentication Basic vs Bearer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013299/web-api-authentication-basic-vs-bearer)

You can make renv work with private repos by adding an `.Rprofile` file to the project like so:

```
source("renv/activate.R")
local({
  project_repos <- c(
    CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org",
    PRIVATE_CRAN = "https://your-private-cran.io"
    )

  options(repos = project_repos)
  options(
    renv.download.headers = function(url) {
      if (grepl(paste0("^", project_repos["PRIVATE_CRAN"]), url))
        return(c(Authorization = paste0("Bearer", Sys.getenv("AUTH_TOKEN"))))
    })
```

This will automatically add the authorization header every time you access a file from the private CRAN.
If you made all the prerequisites, installing a package will look like this:

```
> renv::install("private_packge@2.7.2")
Retrieving 'https://your-private-cran.io/Cran-local/src/contrib/Archive/private_packge/2.7.2/private_packge_2.7.2.tar.gz' ...
    OK [file is up to date]
Installing private_packge [2.7.2] ...
    OK [built from source]
Moving private_packge [2.7.2] into the cache ...
    OK [moved to cache in 1.3 milliseconds]
```

The prerequisites are:

1. Install and configure [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/index.html) for your project.
2. Your private CRAN should be able to accept Authorization header.
3. The authentication token is stored in an environment variable called `AUTH_TOKEN`.
4. Note that I use ***Bearer*** authentication, it means I got a dedicated token from my private CRAN. If you wish to use `username:password`, then you need to use ***Basic*** authentication and the environment variable called `AUTH_TOKEN` should be a base64 encoding of `username:password`.