# maingun reply with OK but nothing happens

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, mailgun

Everything works fine on `Postman` with `x-www-from-urlencoded` and basic auth. Now trying to get my hands dirty, I just get status code 200 with nothing on mailgun, no logs recorded.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
     new AuthenticationHeaderValue("api", "key-withheld-till-a-verdict-has-passed");

  var msg = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
  {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("from",
        $"Excited User <mailgun@sandboxSOMEGUIDHERE.mailgun.org>"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("to","approved-to-receive@mailgun"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("subject", "Test Please Do Not Reply"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text","Thanks for borrowing me your inbox")
  };

  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
     "sandboxSOMEGUIDHERE.mailgun.org/messages");

  request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(msg);

  var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
  // I get 200 status code

  var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
  //I get result = "Mailgun Magnificent API"         
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like the correct response. You sure you're using the correct URL/API endpoint?

Comment: I tested with `Postman` and everything worked perfect.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924996/logging-request-response-messages-when-using-httpclient) and log your request. Look for differences between the postman request and the c# request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it turns out I was getting the `BaseAddress` [not right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438416/why-is-httpclient-baseaddress-not-working). I had to place a slash at the end of the `BaseAddress`.

```
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/");
```

without the slash, I was posting to (note `v3` is missing),

```
https://api.mailgun.net/sandboxSOMEGUIDHERE.mailgun.org/messages
```

After sorting that out, another problem emerged `401 - ANAUTHORIZED`. And with the help of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30862845/7379424) I do,

```
var byteArray = new UTF8Encoding()
    .GetBytes("api:key-withheld-till-a-verdict-has-passed");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
     new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
```

But the reason why `mailgun` was responding with `Ok` still remain mysterious. To investigate further, I used `Postman` to post to,

```
https://api.mailgun.net/sandboxSOMEGUIDHERE.mailgun.org/messages
```

and to my surprise, `Mailgun`  mysteriously responded with `Ok`.