# How can I call a web service that requires authentication

Tags: c#, web-services

I have two web services that listen to different ports on the same server.

First one is used to to authenticate users. I pass my username and password
in the URL and it returns a SessionId variable and my UserName.

How can I call the second service using this information?

Thank you...

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858890/how-to-use-httpclient-to-post-with-authentication

Comment: _I pass my username and password in the URL_. You have a security problem...